# VB program to change text in a script file then run

Tags: vb.net, cmd

I have a .cmd file that is used to update firmware on some network blocks. It contains an IP address. I am trying to make a VB 2010 express program to replace the existing IP address with the IP address the user types in a text box. The main problem is that it appends some crazy characters to the beginning. Here is the code I am using to read the cmd file, change the IP and create a new one with a different name. Then I launch it. The problem is it is adding some characters at the beginning as can be seen in the image below. Can any body explain to me why it is adding the ï»¿ to the beginning of the file? Also if you know how to correct this. Thank you.

NEW FILE AS SEEN IN VBSedit

```
ï»¿set ModuleAddress=
set ModuleInterface=ECT
set ModuleName=BNI ECT-508-105-Z015

set ModuleFirmware="..\..\%ModuleInterface%\%ModuleName%\bniect.nxf"

set ModuleWebserver="..\..\%ModuleInterface%\%ModuleName%\Webserver"

set SipFw="..\..\%ModuleInterface%\%ModuleName%\sip.hex"

call Scripts\fileupload.cmd %ModuleAddress% %SipFw%

call Scripts\webupload.cmd %ModuleAddress% %ModuleWebserver%

call Scripts\fwupdate.cmd %ModuleAddress% %ModuleFirmware%

pause
```

OLD FILE AS SEEN in VBSdedit

```
set ModuleAddress=10.10.0.1

set ModuleInterface=ECT

set ModuleName=BNI ECT-508-105-Z015

set ModuleFirmware="..\..\%ModuleInterface%\%ModuleName%\bniect.nxf"

set ModuleWebserver="..\..\%ModuleInterface%\%ModuleName%\Webserver"

set SipFw="..\..\%ModuleInterface%\%ModuleName%\sip.hex"

call Scripts\fileupload.cmd %ModuleAddress% %SipFw%

call Scripts\webupload.cmd %ModuleAddress% %ModuleWebserver%

call Scripts\fwupdate.cmd %ModuleAddress% %ModuleFirmware%

pause
```

Visual Basic 2010 express code

```
    Dim fileReader As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("C:\Update BNI ECT-508-105-Z015 HW5 FW1.1\Update BNI ECT-508-105-Z015 HW5 FW1.1\Update BNI ECT-508-105-Z015 HW5 FW1.1\+ Tools\netX Update\PROGRAM WHOLE PROJECT BNI ECT-508-105-Z015 192 168 0 100.cmd").Replace("10.10.0.1", TextBox1.Text)
    My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("C:\Update BNI ECT-508-105-Z015 HW5 FW1.1\Update BNI ECT-508-105-Z015 HW5 FW1.1\Update BNI ECT-508-105-Z015 HW5 FW1.1\+ Tools\netX Update\PROGRAM WHOLE PROJECT BNI ECT-508-105-Z015 192 168 0 100 2.cmd", fileReader, False)


    Dim FILE_NAME As String = "C:\Update BNI ECT-508-105-Z015 HW5 FW1.1\Update BNI ECT-508-105-Z015 HW5 FW1.1\Update BNI ECT-508-105-Z015 HW5 FW1.1\+ Tools\netX Update\PROGRAM WHOLE PROJECT BNI ECT-508-105-Z015 192 168 0 100 2.cmd"

    If System.IO.File.Exists(FILE_NAME) = True Then

        Process.Start(FILE_NAME)

    Else

        MsgBox("File Does Not Exist")

    End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can any body explain to me why it is adding the `ï»¿` to the beginning of the file?

That looks like a [Byte Order Mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). To fix it, use one of the `WriteAllText()` overloads that allows you to specify the text encoding, and make sure to use `Encoding.ASCII`.

Comment: Thanks Joel, That worked. I really appreciate your fast and knowledgable response.